# Python XML - incrementally writing XML without duplicating namespaces

Tags: python, xml, stream, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am wondering if there is a way to have a concise namespace declaration of my XML when I am writing it in an incremental manner using `lxml`. Currently, I get duplicated namespaces with the way I generate my XML. See below, where the tags `data` and `oneEntry` duplicate the namespaces:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data xmlns="nsURI1" xmlns:second="nsURI2">
    <oneEntry xmlns:second="nsURI2" xmlns="nsURI1">
        <subEntry1/>
        <second:subEntry2/>
    </oneEntry>
</data>
```

This can be generated from a script like this (inspired by http://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation)

```
from lxml import etree
from io import BytesIO

class XmlWriter(object):
    ROOT_TAG = 'data'
    ENCODING = 'utf-8'
    NSMAP = {
        None: 'nsURI1',
        'second': 'nsURI2'
    }

    def write(self):
        f = BytesIO()
        w = self.writer(f)  # Creates the writer
        next(w)  # Start writing (go to first yield)

        element = etree.Element('oneEntry', nsmap=self.NSMAP)
        etree.SubElement(element, '{nsURI1}subEntry1')
        etree.SubElement(element, '{nsURI2}subEntry2')
        w.send(element)

        w.close() # Closing stream closes root tag
        print(f.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))

    @classmethod
    def writer(cls, out_stream):
        with etree.xmlfile(out_stream, encoding=cls.ENCODING) as xf:
            xf.write_declaration()
            with xf.element(cls.ROOT_TAG, nsmap=cls.NSMAP):
                while True:
                    el = yield
                    xf.write(el)
                    xf.flush()

XmlWriter().write()
```

The part computing one entry is actually a loop generating multiple thousands of entries, therefore my need for a stream.
Now, I understand why this is happening. The root tag in my stream writer is not known by the part computing the entry element. So, during the incremental writing, the namespaces are duplicated on each entry. This will increase (when my file is not compressed) the size of my output.

Any idea how I could still write incrementally my XML, without having to change the structure of it and still use `lxml` preferably?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or a simpler formulation of the problem would be to find a way to link the namespaces defined in a `with xf.element('tag', nsmap={'test': 'uri'}):` and `xf.write(etree.Element('{uri}tag2'))` which is inside the with-block.
Because this outputs:
`<tag xmlns:test="uri"><ns0:tag2 xmlns:ns0="uri"/></tag>`